# How to determine largest resolution of an INTERVAL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

How can I determine the largest resolution of an INTERVAL value?  For example:

- `INTERVAL '100 days and 3 seconds'` => day
- `TIME '20:05' - TIME '12:01:01'` => hour
- `AGE(NOW(), NOW() - INTERVAL '1 MONTH')` => month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't 100% clear so the answer may or may not be exactly what you're looking for, but...

There is a [`justify_interval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function, which you might want to look into.

```
test=# select justify_interval(INTERVAL '100 days 3 seconds');
    justify_interval     
-------------------------
 3 mons 10 days 00:00:03
(1 row)

test=# select justify_interval(TIME '20:05' - TIME '12:01:01');
 justify_interval 
------------------
 08:03:59
(1 row)

test=# select justify_interval(AGE(NOW(), NOW() - INTERVAL '1 MONTH'));
 justify_interval 
------------------
 1 mon
(1 row)
```

For there extract the year, then month, then day, etc. until you come up with a non-zero answer:

```
test=# select extract('mon' from interval '3 mons 10 days 00:00:03');
 date_part 
-----------
         3
```

---

Re your other question in comments:

```
create function max_res(interval) returns interval as $$
select case
       when extract('year' from justify_interval($1)) > 0 or
            extract('mon' from justify_interval($1)) > 0 or
            extract('day' from justify_interval($1)) > 0
       then '1 day'
       when extract('hour' from justify_interval($1)) > 0
       then '1 hour'
       when ...
       end;
$$ language sql immutable strict;
```

Comment: Close and on to something.  However, as indicated in the original post, I'd like to know that '100 days' is specified in days instead of "justifying" it to an interval specified in months.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Then again, why not wrap something like the above into a function that would return day when year or month should get picked up?

Comment: You can either directly compare two intervals.  i.e. select interval1 > interval2;  Also you can extract ('epoch',...) which will extract seconds +/- since jan 1 1970.

Comment: @Denis, I'm not sure I understand your suggestion ("return day when year should be picked-up").  +1, anyway, and could you flesh out the function you propose?

Comment: @Scott, not bad, but comparing two intervals won't tell me the largest time unit:  `INTERVAL '30 HOUR'` is greater than `INTERVAL '1 DAY'`, but the scales are HOUR and DAY, respectively.  Neither will converting to seconds.

Comment: Okay - without the `justify_interval`, your `CASE`/`WHEN` looks like it does what I want.

Comment: No no. You *want* the interval to be justified. `select extract('day' from interval '30 hour'); -- 0`

Answer (score 1):

[`INTERVAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) is 12 bytes and is a struct containing months, days and microseconds and has a range of +/- 178000000 years. It always has a fixed max size of 178000000 years due to the way that it stores this information.

Be careful with your understanding of "a month" because the Julian month is not a constant in the same way that an `hour` or a `minute` is (e.g. how many days are in the month of February? Or how many days are there in a `year`? It's not always 30 or 365 in reality and PostgreSQL updates things correctly. per an interesting conversation on IRC, Adding `1 month`::INTERVAL to January 30th will result in whatever the last day of February because it increments the `tm_mon` member of `struct tm` (and in this case, rolls back to the previous valid date).

---

Ah ha! I get the question now (or at least I think so). You're looking to determine the largest "non-zero integer unit" for a given `INTERVAL`.

PostgreSQL doesn't have a built-in function that returns that information. I think you're going to have to chain a conditional and return type. Some example `PL` code:

```
t := EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM my_time_input);
IF t >= 31104000 THEN
  RETURN 'year';
ELSIF t >= 2592000 THEN
  RETURN 'month';
ELSIF t >= 604800 THEN
  RETURN 'week';
ELSIF t >= 86400 THEN
  RETURN 'day';
ELSIF t >= 3600 THEN
  RETURN 'hour';
ELSIF t >= 60 THEN
  RETURN 'minute'
ELSIF t > 1 THEN
  RETURN 'seconds';
ELSIF t == 1 THEN
  RETURN 'second';
ELSE
  RETURN resolve_largest_sub_second_unit(my_time);
END IF;
```

Comment: The Interval structure under the hood is compound, not a count of microseconds.  Otherwise date/time arithmetic couldn't reasonably work with, for example, daylight savings changes or months of varying lengths.

Comment: You bring up several good points. Let me update my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  I understand the storage type and intervalic date/time arithmetic.  Do you have an answer for the question?

Comment: OH! I get your question now. You're looking to determine the largest non-fractional unit for a given `INTERVAL`, right? Hrm. Editing question with a suggestion.