# Why is result of age() not always equivalent to interval when going back in time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I've come across some unexpected behavior of my SQL code in PostgreSQL 9.6 cornering date calculations. While analyzing, I've found out that Postgres will not always return the same value for going back `n` days and then calculate the duration with `age()`.

Consider this code: We set some day as "base", go 45 days back and then calculate the duration.

```
WITH basedate AS (SELECT '2018-05-01'::date AS b), 
     myperiod AS (SELECT (basedate.b - interval '45 days') AS "startDate",
     basedate.b AS "endDate" FROM basedate)
SELECT age("endDate","startDate") FROM myperiod;
```

I expect this query to always result in `45 days`. However, if I change my `basedate` to `2018-06-01`, I'll get `44 days`.

Why is this the case?

My guess is this is somehow related to May having 31 days. However, I cannot exactely explain why, since both `2018-05-01` and `2018-06-01` will result in the same duration if I change `45 days` to `15 days`.

Comment: Related: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194411) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374453)

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite true.

Your first query returns

```
      age      
---------------
 1 mon 15 days
(1 row)
```

and if you modify the date to `2018-06-01`, you get

```
      age      
---------------
 1 mon 14 days
(1 row)
```

Both are correct, aren't they?

The problem is rather that PostgreSQL treats a month as 30 days in functions like `justify_interval`:

```
SELECT justify_interval('45 days');

 justify_interval 
------------------
 1 mon 15 days
(1 row)
```

But then, the alternative would be to throw an error, and the behavior is clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Laurenz Albe's answer points to the right thing: I should have expected a result starting with `1 mon`.

The problem was actually in the client, in this case OmniDB 2.8. See here: [GitHub OmniDB: Does OmniDB auto-convert intervals to days?](https://github.com/OmniDB/OmniDB/issues/560) The issue was fixed in OmniDB 2.9

In all other clients I've tested I got a result like Laurenz Albe predicted.

So, if you come across here while having a similar issue: By any means, check if the problem is in your client or the library you use.